# Why does Entity Framework add-migration remember old class variable name

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration

I have some classes and when I run the add-migration command it created a migration file with a class variable that does not exist in my project.

I tried everything to find out where it goes wrong, but without any luck.

In my class I have this line.
public MSApprover MSProcessMasterApprover_Customer { get; set; }

But when I run add-migration is writes this line in the migration file.
public MSApprover MSProcessMasterApprover_CustomerId { get; set; }

I have no idea where the Id comes from.

I tried to clean my solution, removed the migration from VS, removed migration from the database, deleting the bin and obj folder and deleting the denv casche.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solutions my self.

I put a virtual after publich and a ? after the type to make it accept NULL. Like this.

```
public virtual string? MyValue { Get; Set;}
```

That did the trick.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).